# PowerShell Add Windows Local Printer

Tags: windows, powershell, printing

I'm having trouble running all of these powershell lines together as an automated process to install a local Windows printer on ANY user machine

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\ANYUser\Desktop\*.exe" -ArgumentList "/S /v/qn" 

Pnputil /add-driver "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\lib\*.inf" 

Add-PrinterPort -Name "File:(print to file)" 

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "NAME PDF" 

Add-Printer -Name "NAME OF PRINTER" -PortName "File:(print to file)" -DriverName "NAME PDF"
```

I can execute each line individually but as I said I'm trying to automate it so I can push it out to ANY user machine with the EXE and this powershell script. I'm still new to PS but getting better, appreciate any help.

Dave

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to add the [`-wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.3#-wait) parameter to Start-Process so it will wait until the executables have finished running before proceeding with the rest of the setup:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\ANYUser\Desktop\*.exe" -ArgumentList "/S","/v","/qn" -Wait 

Pnputil /add-driver "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.50\lib\*.inf" 

Add-PrinterPort -Name "File:(print to file)" 

Add-PrinterDriver -Name "NAME PDF" 

Add-Printer -Name "NAME OF PRINTER" -PortName "File:(print to file)" -DriverName "NAME PDF"
```

In addition, `-ArgumentList` should be formatted as an array looks like this:
"Members","Of","The","Array". One argument in each entry.